# Why am I not able to use User SQL Server Authentication using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard?

Tags: sql-server, datasource, wizard, data-export

[Data Source Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmcMy.jpg)

I am trying to export a table from one database to another using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard (MS SQL Server Management Studio 17).

For reasons, I am not able to use SQL Server Authentication, it would prompt error as seen in the screen shot.

It would work if I changed authentication to use Windows Authentication.   However, I need to use SQL Server Authentication to be able to select the desired table to export. Those tables would be invisible using Windows Authentication.     I logged into the database using SQL Server Authentication.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?  Thanks!

Error Detail:

```
Invalid authorization specification
Invalid connection string attribute (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.DTSWizard.GetOpenedConnection(WizardInputs wizardInputs, String connEntryName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.Step1.OnLeavePage(LeavePageEventArgs e)
```

> Blockquote

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74739621/edit) your question to include the error message as text instead of a screen shot - the copy details button on that dialog makes it easy for you to do so.

Comment: Are you trying to use your Windows username and password with SQL Server Authentication? That doesn't work, SQL Server Authentication logons are completely seperate from Windows Authentication logons and are not compatible with one another.

Comment: Error detail added..... thanks Both!  I actually used SQL Server  user/pw for SQL Server Authentication.  I am not sure why I was "forced" to use windows authentication and I did not intentionally set it up that way.  In fact, I was able to use SQL Server authentication the first time I ran the wizard but the next time I ran the wizard, I can only use windows authentication.